# Add button to a GroupBox

Tags: vb.net, button, groupbox

i have a problem. I have a button who is creating an other button, but i want that the new button will be in a groupbox, but it's not working, the button is replacing all of the groupbox.

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Dim button As New Button
    button.Location = New Drawing.Point(10, 500)
    button.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(171, 23)
    button.Text = TextBox1.Text
    button.Controls.Add(GroupBox1)
    Me.Controls.Add(button)

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.Controls.Add(GroupBox1)
```

Here you are adding the GroupBox to the Button, not the other way around.

```
GroupBox1.Controls.Add(button)
```

Is what you want.

Comment: Lol thank you its now working, i'm sooooo bad, have to learn :)

Comment: Don't we all! Glad to help.